# Kafka Topic Distribution among brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

When creating topics, can we determine which broker will be the leader for the topic? Are topics balanced across brokers in Kafka? (Considering the topics have just one partition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka does manage this internally and you don't need to worry about this in general: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_leader_balancing

If you create a new topic, Kafka will select a broker based on load. If a topic has only one partitions, it will only be hosted on a single broker (plus followers if you have multiple replicas), because a partitions cannot be split over multiple brokers in Kafka.

Nevertheless, you can get the information which broker host what topic and you can also "move" topics and partitions: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion